# Can anyone explain Next.js generatestaticparams() server function

Tags: next.js

I am a beginner in programming and have read the basics of react and started nextjs 13. Currently, I am facing difficulty in understanding generatestaticparams() server function from the documentation like the basics of it, what does it do and for what it is used for. Is it used for generating static pages.
Can anyone explain me in simple terms.
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-static-params

I have seen some youtube tutorials but was not able to grasp the concept of it. Most of the tutorials were fetching some kind of data like videos or todo list from some api etc.

Comment: this [video](https://youtu.be/UgseormfMc4?t=6m1s) by Josh, [YouTube short](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/zcVoO8bF474) & [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sq-4lSElN1w) also explains this concept. Although I don't understand it completely. I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

First, I would mention that `getStaticParams` is not essential when starting out learning React or Next. I personally have been using Next for many years and never actually used `getStaticParams`. It's also not an easy concept to understand, so don't feel bad when it is not making sense to you, yet.

I would also point out that it can easily be confused with [getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props) which is something different.

So my suggestion would be to ignore this section of the docs and move on to something else, something that is easier to understand for you at this point.

But to answer your question: **`getStaticParams` is a way to speed up your website by fetching data as early as possible.**

###### Example

Let's imagine you are building a personal blog. And let's also imagine you have already published some posts on Medium that you want to now show on your personal blog. One way to do that is to use the Medium API to fetch a list of your posts and display them.

Now whenever someone visits your blog you could make a call to the Medium API to get this list of blog posts. But since your blog posts don't change very often, you might want to fetch this list of posts only once, in *the beginning*, and not *on every request*. *In the beginning* here means when you build and publish your website. And that's what `getStaticParams` can help you with. It provides you a way to fetch this list of blog posts only once as opposed to fetching them on every request, which will reduce the loading times of your blog.

Comment: I think you should replace `getStaticParams` with `getStaticPaths` in your answer. Next.js 13 App Router has `generateStaticParams` which is equivalent to `getStaticPaths` from Next.js Page Router.