# How to use generateStaticParams in Next.js 13.4 with code examples?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How to use generateStaticParams in next.js 13.4?  Anyone can give some code snippets with examples?

I am expecting a working example code. I have tried but have not been able to get a clear understanding.

```js
product/[id]/page.tsx

import { getProducts } from "../getProducts";

interface Product {
  id: number,
  title: string,
  description: string,
  price: number,
  discountPercentage: number,
  rating: number,
  stock: number,
  brand: string,
  category: string,
  thumbnail: string,
  images: string[],
}

async function getProduct( id: number) {
  const res = await fetch(`https://dummyjson.com/products/${id}`);
  return res.json();
}

export default async function page({params}: any) {
  console.log('params', params);
  const  product  = await getProduct(params.id);

  return (
    <div style={{
      border: '2px solid cyan',
      padding: '20px',
      margin: '10px'
    }}>
      <div>I am product page {JSON.stringify(product)}</div>
    </div>
  )
}

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const { products } = await getProducts();
  return products.map((p: Product) => ({ id: p.id.toString()}));
}



// getProducts.ts
export async function getProducts() {
  const res = await fetch("https://dummyjson.com/products");
  return res.json();
}


// product/layout.tsx

export default async function ProductsLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const { products } = await getProducts();

  return <section style={{
    border: '2px solid purple',
    padding: '20px',
    margin: '10px',
    display: 'flex', gap: '2rem'
  }}>
    <p>I am Product layout</p>
    <ul>
      {products.map(({ id, title }: {
        id: number,
        title: string
      }) => (
        <li key={id}>
          <Link href={`/product/${id}`}>{title}</Link>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
    {children}
    </section>;
}
```

I was doing some POC, so I have attached a sample code.  How to use generateStaticParams in next.js 13.4?  Anyone can give some code snippets with examples? I am expecting a working example code. I have tried but have not been able to get a clear understanding.

Comment: +1 on this. I haven't been able to find any example that explains its use either. I was able to generate the dynamic route even without using this method. So what's the use of this method?

Comment: What's exactly the issue with the snippet you provided?

Comment: @Gangula when using `generateStaticParams`, dynamic routes are statically generated at build time. Otherwise, they are generated on-demand at request time.

Comment: @ivanatias, so does that mean it is better in performance to use `generateStaticParams`? I don't see any major difference with or without it.

Comment: @ivanatias It got resolved. there was a typo at this line <Link href={`/product/${id}`}>{title}</Link> => <Link href={`/products/${id}`}>{title}</Link>

Comment: @Gangula Well, a cached static page will always have a better performance, but it depends on the page's requirements. You won't see any difference if in development mode, only in production.

Comment: I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75116148/6908282) which is similar, but the answer provided is not relevant

Comment: this [video](https://youtu.be/UgseormfMc4?t=6m1s) by Josh, [YouTube short](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/zcVoO8bF474) & [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sq-4lSElN1w) also explains this concept. Although I don't understand it completely. I hope it helps

Comment: No matter what I do I can't make the generateStaticParams be called during build time